# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

Im getting that error when executing this line:

```
if( 'POST' === $request->getMethod( ) ) {
```

Doing a var dump on $request->getMethod( ) gives me: `string(3) "GET"` And is fine.

So i dont get why im getting a preg macth error. some more details:

```
1 error
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
INFO - Matched route "done_punctis_brand_apicodes_edit" (parameters: "_controller": "Done\PunctisBundle\Controller\BrandController::apiEditAction", "id": "1", "apicode": "3", "_route": "done_punctis_brand_apicodes_edit") 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session 
DEBUG - Reloading user from user provider. 
DEBUG - SET NAMES UTF8 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.referer AS referer3, t0.salt AS salt4, t0.password AS password5, t0.verified AS verified6, t0.score AS score7, t0.avatar AS avatar8, t0.registration AS registration9, t0.role AS role10, t0.info_id AS info_id11 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
DEBUG - Username "--------------" was reloaded from user provider. 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.avatar AS avatar3, t0.description AS description4, t0.url AS url5, t0.address AS address6, t0.registration AS registration7, t0.verified AS verified8, t0.maxpoints AS maxpoints9, t0.explimitsocial AS explimitsocial10, t0.explimitpoll AS explimitpoll11, t0.explimitapi AS explimitapi12, t0.credit AS credit13, t0.world_id AS world_id14 FROM brand t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.referer AS referer3, t0.salt AS salt4, t0.password AS password5, t0.verified AS verified6, t0.score AS score7, t0.avatar AS avatar8, t0.registration AS registration9, t0.role AS role10, t0.info_id AS info_id11 FROM user t0 INNER JOIN user_brand_administered ON t0.id = user_brand_administered.user_id WHERE user_brand_administered.brand_id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2, t0.description AS description3, t0.actionid AS actionid4, t0.secretid AS secretid5, t0.brand AS brand6, t0.points AS points7, t0.premium AS premium8, t0.image AS image9, t0.ppa AS ppa10 FROM apicodes t0 WHERE t0.brand = ? AND t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". 
CRITICAL - ErrorException: Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1129 (uncaught exception) at /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1129
```

**Stack Trace**

```
in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1129   
            if ('variable' === $token[0]) {
                if (false === $optional || !array_key_exists($token[3], $defaults) || (isset($parameters[$token[3]]) && (string) $parameters[$token[3]] != (string) $defaults[$token[3]])) {
                    if (!$isEmpty = in_array($tparams[$token[3]], array(null, '', false), true)) {
                                                if ($tparams[$token[3]] && !preg_match('#^'.$token[2].'$#', $tparams[$token[3]])) {
                            $message = sprintf('Parameter "%s" for route "%s" must match "%s" ("%s" given).', $token[3], $name, $token[2], $tparams[$token[3]]);
                            if ($this->strictRequirements) {
                                throw new InvalidParameterException($message);
```

Comment: Try adding parentheses around $request->getMethod( ). Maybe its reading $request, which is the object, only.

Comment: What about $request->isMethod('POST') ?

Comment: none of that work, the parenthesis around $request->getMethod( ) or the $request->isMethod('POST') ... same error:  Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1129

Comment: @DomingoSL: Uh... where is the source for the line with the `preg_match`? That's kind of important.

Comment: @Jon please check the edit i made; Stack Trace

Comment: @UselessIntern That's bad advice, please don't offer solutions if you only guessing and don't know what you're doing. There is no way that the `->method` is being dropped and the `===` is comparing only the `$request`, that's impossible given the code posted.

Comment: `$tparams[$token[3]]` what's in here?

Comment: no idea, thats part of the symfony core

Comment: you could do a var_dump to see, it's somewhat important. And I'd like to know which class and method it is.

Comment: How did you find out it breaks on this part of your code? I don't see any reason why this could happen on this particular line. What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: using just a die() function just after the if sentence still trigger the error, if i move it just before it just die.